Calculating deflection on a beam
This is for a hobby project, and to learn a little about elasticity along the way.
I have a triangle wedge comb piece of decreasing width and angle for which the cross section is shown here:

For each of the teeth, I was able to measure how much it bends when a force is applied at the tip.
Can I use this information to find out how much this new piece below would bend under the same load without having to make the piece and test it based on what I know from the first piece? Assume all materials are the same. The wedges have been replaced by rectangular beams with the same length and of the base width in the original wedge.

In other words: given a triangle wedge, how much is the displacement at the edge reduced when the wedge is replaced by a rectangular beam?

This is the kind of math that certain engineers knows very well but is otherwise pretty obscure. That said, the concepts you're probably looking for is the "bending moment" and "bending stresses" of the beam. The MIT OCW notes found here seem like a good place to start, particularly section 9.4

woah. that looks overly complicated. On second thought I'll take the thinner wedge as an approximation of a rectangular one and just use that as a baseline assuming a relationship between thickness and deflection (stacking thin rectangles)

I am not sure about the triangular wedge but as a starting point for a rectangular beam it sounds like you need Euler-Bernoulli theory for the deflection of a cantilevered beam.
I think the lecture notes cited in the link above are excessively complicated and involved for your purposes.  I have recently written an article where I break down how the theory works in simple and intuitive terms which I can send to you if you need an introduction.
The expression which you need for the deflection in the $y$ direction is
$y(x) = \frac{F L^3}{2 E I } \bigg(  \frac{x^2}{L^2}  - \frac{x^3}{3 L^3} \bigg). $
I found that it is difficult to exactly get this expression using the more involved Euler-Bernoulli beam theory, but you can get quite close without it, which at least justifies the form of the final equation.

I found this video explanation helpful. It discretizes the problem lengthwise and adds the deflection contributions as a series. https://youtu.be/53SMzJyAdIQ&t=4565
